# KestrelServerOptions.ApplicationSchedulingMode in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: kestrel-http-server

I have a question about [KestrelServerOptions.ApplicationSchedulingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.applicationschedulingmode?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in .NET Core 2.2

```
public class KestrelServerOptions
{
    public SchedulingMode ApplicationSchedulingMode { get; set; }
}

public enum SchedulingMode
{
    // Use the transport provided ApplicationScheduler 
    Default,
    // Use the thread pool
    ThreadPool,
    // Run on the "current" thread
    Inline
}
```

For socket transport, is `Default` the same as `ThreadPool`?

For libuv transport, Does `Default` mean using libuv's own native thread?